# Why is App Store Connect review getting CKError QuotaExceeded

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, cloudkit

Please help!

I am trying to get my iOS CloudKit based app through Apple Store Review. This is my first App submission. I am able to use my app and have deployed my cloudkit dashboard to production, but when the app store connect tries to review my app they get the CKError "QuotaExceeded" when they try to save their first CKRecord in their Private Database. The record is only like 500 bytes. The apple documentation indicates this means that the user (in this case Apple) has insufficient storage space on their icloud server, which seems surprising. Has anyone run into this issue? I cannot find any reason why this would be showing up...

Comment: It sounds strange. can you show the code which saves the record?

Comment: Hi John,  this was resolved.  In the end, I had put in extra code to be more verbose in case of this error (Telling the user to manage their iCloud storage), and also repeated to the App Review that they had to make sure they had enough storage.  They denied my appeal and repeated their assertions, but then the next time I submitted the error seemed to not happen on their end (confirmed by my analysis that there was a lack of database error on CloudKit dashboard logs), so I think they 'silently' fixed it on their end.

Answer (score 0):

this was resolved. In the end, I had put in extra code to be more verbose in case of this error (Telling the user to manage their iCloud storage), and also repeated to the App Reviewer that they had to make sure they had enough storage. They denied my appeal and repeated their assertions, but then the next time I submitted the error seemed to not happen on their end (confirmed by my analysis that there was a lack of database error on CloudKit dashboard logs), so I think they 'silently' fixed it on their end.